# how to extract pdf data/table to html/php and upload to database with out loosing format or text

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a project where I need to extract data from a pdf file, and insert it into mysqldb. I found a sample project that almost suits my requirements, but this project mixes the values of parts on the quotation.

My question is how do I extract data from an pdf with out losing text, and format, including pdf tables,

Project I found on GitHub :  git clone https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js 
you can find a demo here :  Web DEMO: https://ronnywang.github.io/pdf-table-extractor/

What I need is a pdf converter like: https://www.pdftohtml.net

After the extraction is completed the html/php data must be uploaded to mysql db.

Comment: the simple way is to export PDF to HTML code and next put this to a database. You can find many PHP projects export PDF to HTML on GitHub or Google. 

example https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9423-PHP-Convert-PDF-to-HTML-using-Poppler.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! There should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research... What did you try?

Comment: I only need to convert the pdf data into html